# Only one field allowed to be filled Angular

Tags: angular, forms, validation

im trying to make Angular 14 validator, that will validate form only when one of some given FormControls have values.
For example, I have 5 input fields, and form could be valid only when one of them is filled and valid. When I fill other field, form should turn invalid. Form should be invalid also when none of the fields are filled. So basically I would call this validator "at most one".

I have tried to enable/disable fields when one of them is filled but that didn't seem to work properly, as sometimes it fell into infinite loop. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: share the code tried till now, if possible a stackblitz with the issue and expected result.

Comment: You can create your own validator, with the formgroup as input if set on the formGroup, or the formcontrol himself if on the control. In the later, you can access related formcontrols with formControl.parent.get('otherCtrl').
see https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators

Comment: Thanks guys for feedback, but I already solved the problem by writing my own validator as @hunB suggested. I posted it as answear so if someone has problem like me, he could be guided by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved the problem, here is the solution:

```
public static oneAllowed(formGroup: FormGroup) {
  let counterIsValue = 0;

  for (const key in formGroup.controls) {
    if (formGroup.controls.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const control: FormControl = formGroup.controls[key] as FormControl;
      if (control.value) counterIsValue++;
    }
  }
  return counterIsValue === 1 ? null : { oneAllowed: true };
}
```

If someone has same problem you can base on that solution.